# convert numeric vector to character vector

Tags: r

I have a vector in following format

```
vec1 <- c(101.34,110.00,145.36,124.00,235.25,123.01)
```

I want the following output

```
vect1 <- c("101.34","110.00","145.36","124.00")
```

I have tried using

```
vect1 <- as.character(vect1)
```

but I got the output like this

```
vect1 = c("101.34","110","145.36","124")`
```

Comment: `sprintf("%.2f", vec1)`

Answer (score 1):

You can get your desired result using `format` function:

```
format(vec1,digits = 5)
format(vec1,zero.print = T)
```

or using `sprintf` function as Jogo said:

```
sprintf("%.2f", vec1)
```